# Why the decision boundaries are linear in an input space?

Tags: decision-theory

In the section 4.2.1 in "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Bishop", the author considered a 2-class problem and assumed class-conditional densities $p(x | C_k)$ are Gaussian, and all have the same covariance matrix. The posterior pdf of class $C_1$ is expressed below,
$$
p(C_1 | x) = \sigma(w^T x + w_0) \\
\sigma(a) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(a)} \\
w = \Sigma^{-1} (\mu_1 - \mu_2) \\
w_0 = -0.5 \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_1 + 0.5 \mu_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_2 + \ln \frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}
$$

$\Sigma$ and $\mu_i$ are the covariance matrix and the mean corresponding to class $C_i$

This is the remark I am confused,

> The resulting decision boundaries correspond to surfaces along which the posterior probabilities $p(C_k|x)$ are constant and so will be given by linear functions of x, and therefore the decision boundaries are linear in input space.

Because there are only two classes, I interpret the remark as, the resulting decision boundaries correspond to surfaces along which the posterior probabilities $p(C_1|x) = p(C_2|x) = 0.5$. How can I verify the decision boundaries are linear? and what are the expressions of the decision boundaries?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Are you asking why $\sigma(w^T + w_0)$ defines a linear boundary, although $\sigma$ is non-linear? Or do you wonder why the boundary is described by the above function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision boundary is 'the' space where the final prediction is exactly the threshold (usually $0.5$ if it is a balanced problem). So this is exactly the critical area where the model switches from a positive to a negative prediction and vice versa. In the case of logistic regression it looks quite nonlinear (because of all of these exponential functions) but let us simply calculate:

Given a single data row $x$ (consisting of all the features) the prediction for $x$ being $C_1$ is
$$P[Y=C_1|X=x] = \sigma(\text{linear function}(x))$$
Since $P[Y=C_2|X=x] = 1-P[Y=C_1|X=x]$ the sets
$$\{x : P[Y=C_1|X=x]=0.5\}$$
and
$$\{x : P[Y=C_2|X=x]=0.5\}$$
are actually equal and this set is called the decision boundary.

So where is $P[Y=C_1|X=x] = \sigma(\text{linear function}(x))$ exactly $0.5$? Since $\sigma$ is strictly monotonously increasing ($\sigma' > 0$), it is injective and $\sigma(0) = 0.5$ meaning that $0$ is the only value where the sigma function attains $0.5$. So
$$\sigma(\text{linear function}(x)) = 0.5 \iff \text{linear function}(x)=0$$
Let's say we have two features $x_1$ and $x_2$ and the linear function looks like $ax_1 + bx_2 + c$ then we see that the decision boundary is exactly those $(x_1, x_2)$ where
$$ax_1 + bx_2 + c = 0 \iff x_1 = -(bx_2 + c)/a$$
and that is the condition for a line (first parameter = second parameter multiplied by a weight).

NOTE: The way I way(s) keep this in my head is that the decision boundary is actually linear and the switch from $C_1$ to $C_2$ is 'hard'. I.e. if we replace the sigmoid function with something like $1_{x >= 0.5}$, the function that is $1$ when the input is $>=0.5$ and $0$ otherwise then we also get kind of a logistic regression model. The sigmoid function makes this transition a bit more soft (that is also important for the computation of the gradient when we want to train this model!).

Another interpretation is this: Let us recall that computing the linear function yields a real scalar. What $\sigma$ does is that is 'squashes' that (from the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$) to the interval $(0, 1)$. Hence, it is also sometimes called the 'squashing' function.